# Regex for first two character of string alphabet and rest should be numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate a string like

- AB01
- CA50

Case

1. Total number of string must be four.
2. First two character must be alphabet
3. Last two character must be numeric.

I have used following expression but it can validate only first two character as a Alphabet, how to validate last 2 and total number?

```
var re = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]{2}');
re.test('CC8A8');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below regex will help you to validate:

```
var re = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}$');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the pattern to validate 2 digits at the last.

```
var re = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]{2}\\d{2}$", "m");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var re = /^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{2}$/;
```

no need to use `RegExp` object for this.